# CSS Flex-box not acting responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Within my project I have a container `<div>` to which I add a border so it's visible to the user.

I add `display: flex;` to the container so it can take advantage of flex box. My current code works perfectly. This is because it is currently fully responsive, meaning when I resize the window from the right or left side, the container also moves which is perfect for responsiveness.

Here is my current code:

```
 <div class="flex-container">
            <h1>YO!</h1>
 </div>

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

However, when I add a width and height to the **.flex-container**, it doesn't act responsive when I resize the window - the container doesn't move with it.

So this happens when I add this to the container:

```
width: 350px;
height: 615px;
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Is there a certain way to set a width and height of the container that has `display: flex;` set on it? Thank you.

Comment: When you set a fixed pixel width and height to an element, there's no reason for it to act responsive. You can use percentage values for width and height, which will be responsive. (which has nothing to do with flex BTW)

Comment: why not just use `max-width: 350px;` and set the width to `100%` and maybe set height to `min-height:615px;`?

Comment: Whats the goal? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of

```
width: 350px;
```

Do like this

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 350px;
```

Here is a link https://jsfiddle.net/mironomadic/5cvgmpth/3/ for it working

Also if you need to stack the columns on top of each other change

```
flex-direction: row;
```

To

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: You are most welcome, don't forget to mark as answered if it did the trick for you :)

Comment: I have done, thanks again mate, best answer by far!

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're adding a fixed width and height. This is irregardless of wether the element is set to display flex.

You're telling the container that it has a static, fixed width of 350px. 350px is an absolute value, it isn't relative to the size of the screen.

If you're using flex, you can use flex-basis and set a percentage to set the width of the container, and even more advanced: use flex-grow or flex-shrink to responsively shrink or expand the container, depending on the container size.

Comment: Hello, I have added **flex-basis: 30%;** as you mentioned to do(set width as a % value)

Comment: However the website still does not act responsive.

Comment: flex-basis pertains to the items, not to the container. In this case, you should look at using responsive unit types like rem, em, or %. If you want to use px, that is completely fine, you can just add a media query to make it responsive.

Comment: Ah so rem and em and % are units designed to make something responsive?

Comment: Yes, because they adjust depending on parent element. 

For example, lets say your container is set to use width: 5rem, height: 5rem. In your html selector, you have font-size set to 16px. If you want to make it respnosive, simply changing the font-size to maybe, 14px, will also change the container, because rem is in response to the root font size.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a regular `width` parameter isn't very responsive design.

Changing `width: 350px` to `max-width: 350px` will likely achieve the result you are looking for (although this size doesn't leave much room for growth, it will shrink in response to changing window size below 350px width).